# Watson Document Conversion service timeout on pdf redbook files

Tags: timeout, ibm-watson, document-conversion

When trying the Watson Document Conversion service on the following redbook: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/ga195486.pdf, I get timeout error. I verified the size is less than 50 MB. Any guidance on how to handle such files?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to try to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The pdf document you tried to convert timed out because it took longer to convert than the time limit we have set. We adjusted these limits so now you should be able to convert this pdf.